# Prove using the epsilon-delta definition that $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\ \frac{1+x}{2-x}=\frac12$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Prove using the epsilon-delta definition that
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\ \dfrac{1+x}{2-x}=\frac12.
$$
My try:
$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}\ f(x)=b$ the $$|f(x)-b|<\epsilon$$
$$|f(x)-b|=|(1+x)/(2-x) -1/2)=|3x/(4-2x)|$$

but where do I go from here?

Comment: Can you be a little bit more clear with "my try: lim from x to a of f(x)=b the |f(x)-b|"?

Answer (score 4):

$$\forall x,\qquad |x|\leqslant\frac12\implies\left|\frac{1+x}{2-x}-\frac12\right|=\left|\frac{3x}{2(2-x)}\right|\leqslant|x|$$

Comment: how do you know the last inequality is true and is this not a contradiction since you start with |x| and end with |x|??? that where I was confused

Comment: No. You might want to describe precisely the contradiction you see in it. Note that there are **two** inequalities there, maybe you missed the $\implies$ sign between the first one and the second one.

Comment: ok I see that now but how do you prove the last inequality?

Comment: Just tell me. $ $

Comment: What are you implying when you say for all $x$? Are you implying for all $x$ such that $\vert x\vert\leq\frac{1}{2}$? Or are you implying for all $x$ without any condition?

Comment: I cant seem to figure out the logic

Comment: $[\forall x, P(x)\implies Q(x)]$ says that for every $x$, $P(x)$ implies $Q(x)$. That is, for every $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds, $Q(x)$ holds as well (and it says nothing about those $x$ such that $P(x)$ does not hold).

Comment: @sarah Were you able to prove the implication now?